# Neo4j http.log empty

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to turn on http logging for an Enterprise 2.0 Neo4j server.

After following [this documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html), and adding the following likes to `neo4j-server.properties`:

```
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=true

# Logging policy file that governs how HTTP log output is presented and
# archived. Note: changing the rollover and retention policy is sensible, but
# changing the output format is less so, since it is configured to use the
# ubiquitous common log format
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

the `data/log/http.log` file is still zero bytes even after restarting the server and then running a basic Ruby script that inserts nodes (upon request if needed).

I'm guessing I'm missing something completely obvious here so bear with me. Thanks.

UPDATE on 9/26/14

I'm still seeing this issue for Neo4j 2.1.2

Comment: Looks fine to me, can you check your logs in data/logs/* and data/graph.db/messages.log if there is any error message that could be related to this? Perhaps some permission issue?

Comment: Humm, nope. Maybe it's because my HTTP calls are coming from 127.0.0.1 and hitting the server which is also 127.0.0.1.  I'm going to try again soon and post what other insight I can find.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue using neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06. Making the same setting changes in neo4j-community-1.9.5 does produce messages in http log.

Comment: @TheoBriscoe LMK if you find any solution and I'll do the same

Comment: Im see the same error in the latest enterprise-2.0.0.  Other log files being populated just fine and I havn't changed any logging settings besides what @seenickcode did.  Is this a bug

Answer (score 1):

has anyone managed to get the http logs to work?

There was a possible solution on google groups that you could touch the http.log file before starting the server, but still get an empty log file.

For the time being we might try to put a reverse proxy in to log the req and response.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this problem in Neo4j 2.0.1. I added an issue to the Neo4j Github issue tracker in hopes of a resolution.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2219

Comment: As a follow up, this has been resolved as of 6a73d53 (Neo4j 2.0.4).